# NSTextAlignmentJustified exception with arabic string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsparagraphstyle

I am using Arabic string and I want to justify it inside `UITextView`.

I am retrieving incoming attributingString in the textView and enumerate the `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` to edit it like this :

```
NSMutableAttributedString * mstring = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:_textView.attributedText];

[_textView.attributedText enumerateAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, _textView.attributedText.length) options:0
                                  usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
                                      NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = (NSMutableParagraphStyle *)value;
                                      if (paragraphStyle.alignment == NSTextAlignmentRight) {


                                          paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
                                          paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
                                          paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft;
                                          [mstring addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:range];
                                          [self.textView setAttributedText:mstring];
                                      }


}];
```

I found that, if the attributed string is Arabic, the application crashed, but if it is English, it is working normally.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Anyone that solved this issue can let us know how to do it?

Comment: i found that it is crash for some fonts only, try to change font and it will be work. @fabregas88